# Why can't my BufferedInputStream.read() receive -1?

Tags: java, json, tcp

Hy guys I've been trying to write a program that uses TCP to transmit JSON strings. The problem is that when I call `BufferedInputStream.read()` I can't receive any `-1` to indicate the end of a JSON string.

My server code is:

```
public void listen() {
    try {
        if (getClient() != null) {
            String jst = null;
            Message msg = null;
            InputStream in = getClient().getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream inBuf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while (getClient() != null) {
                System.out.println("Receiving Data...");
                try {
                    int i;  
                    while ((i = inBuf.read()) != -1) {  
                        baos.write(i);  
                    }  
                    jst = baos.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Bad Connection.");
                    stopStream();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(jst);
                msg = MessageFactory.fromJSON(jst);
                if (msg.getType().equals(StartMessage.defaultType)) {
                    startStream((StartMessage) msg);
                } else if (msg.getType().equals(StreamMessage.defaultType)) {
                    streaming((StreamMessage) msg);
                } else if (msg.getType().equals(
                        StopStreamMessage.defaultType)) {
                    stopStream();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My client code is:

```
public void sendStart(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    String jst = makeStart();
    out.write(jst.getBytes());
    System.out.println("data sent: " + jst);
}
```

When I was debugging it I saw that there was data that `baos.write(i);` wrote into `i`. However the it seems like there is no `-1` in the data so I can only see `jst = baos.toString();` either I terminate the client or wait for the time out.

This is what I got:

```
{"format":"raw","width":320,"type":"startstream","height":240}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}{"data":"[B@41635617","type":"image"}
Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 62.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at au.edu.benjamin.message.MessageFactory.fromJSON(MessageFactory.java:14)
    at au.edu.benjamin.transmission.TransListenerThread.listen(TransListenerThread.java:78)
    at au.edu.benjamin.transmission.TransListenerThread.run(TransListenerThread.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
null
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at au.edu.benjamin.transmission.TransListenerThread.listen(TransListenerThread.java:79)
    at au.edu.benjamin.transmission.TransListenerThread.run(TransListenerThread.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The exception is because of the unexpected '{', which should be separated from the former JSON string but it didn't.

Can someone tell me where is the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe your stream is already using -1 as a poison.

Comment: So your stream from the client is kept open? That would explain why you don't get a `-1`--you get that when the end of input is reached and the input has not ended.

Comment: -1 indicates the stream has been closed - not that the end of a JSON string has been received. You'll have to detect that yourself.

Comment: That explains a lot! But how can I detect the end of a JSON string? The data I'm trying to transmit is IMG data, so there could be `}` in the data. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ImputStream.read() call on a TCP stream doesn't return -1 once the message ends, instead it is waiting for a new byte (in fact, such a stream only returns -1 if it is closed).

In order to achieve the functionality you want, you could use a string termination character in the end (\0) if you don't use it somewhere else in your message or you could send the size of the JSON-message before you send it itself and read in that size.

Comment: Thanks! How can I attach `\0` into the data? And how can I retrieve it when I receive the data?

Comment: Appending is easy. Just add the character '\0;' at the end of the string you are sending. ex. `send += '\0'`. Reading is also quite easy, just cast everything you get in your while-loop to a character and test for equality with the string-termination character. If you find, break out of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I missedited the above comment. I mean the character '\0' and not '\0;'

Comment: A read on an inputstream does return -1 as by contract of the input stream if the inputstream is at the end, so if it is closed !